# Subscribers are missing messages; Is this a bug with Rx or its me doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a single Window WPF application with the following constructor

```
        numbers = Observable.Generate(DateTime.Now,
                                         time => true,
                                         time => DateTime.Now,
                                         time => { return new     Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).NextDouble() * 99 + 2; },
                                         time => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));


        numbers.ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(s => list1.Items.Add(s.ToString("##.00")));

        numbers.Where(n => n < 10).ObserveOnDispatcher().
            Subscribe(s => list2.Items.Add(s.ToString("##.00")));
```

Now here is the screenshot of the lists - Notice 3.76 is missing from the left list... This behavior is intermittent.

[image]

Comment: "Is this a bug with Rx or its me doing it wrong?" - are you giving odds?

Comment: I am just asking a questions. The odds definitely weren't in my favor.

Comment: Image appears to be a broken link.

Comment: I can view it just fine, Your browser/computer might be blocking images from sites other than the one you're browsing. Here is the URL http://s22.postimg.org/9paxw9rq9/Rx_bug.png

Comment: It appears that the corporate network was blocking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that you are doing it wrong. Rx is working perfectly.

When you create an observable you are creating the definition of a sequence of values over time, not the actual sequence of values over time. This means that whenever you have a subscriber to the observable you are creating new instances of the observable for each subscriber.

So, in your case you have two instances of this sequence operating:

```
var numbers =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            DateTime.Now,
            time => true,
            time => DateTime.Now,
            time => new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
                .NextDouble() * 99 + 2,
            time => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

Now, since you are subscribing to this observable twice in immediate succession the two instances of this observable would be trying to generate values at almost the same time. So the value `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` would be the same most of the time, but now always. The value returned from `new Random(x).NextDouble()` is the same for the same `x`, so hence why most of the time you get the same value from the two instances of the observable. It's just when `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` is different that you get two different values and it appears that the subscribers are missing values.

---

Here's an alternative version that should work as you expected initially:

```
var rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

var numbers =
    Observable
        .Generate(0, n => true, n => 0,
            n => rnd.NextDouble() * 99 + 2,
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

var publishedNumbers = numbers.Publish();

publishedNumbers
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(s => list1.Items.Add(s.ToString("##.00")));

publishedNumbers
    .Where(n => n < 10)
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(s => list2.Items.Add(s.ToString("##.00")));

publishedNumbers.Connect();
```

Comment: Great observation. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: You made my day... I changed the code to use Second instead of Millisecond now I don't see that problem anymore.

Comment: @fahadash - Changing it to seconds doesn't get rid of the problem, it just makes it 1000 times less likely. And you're then not producing random numbers properly. You need to refactor the observable and maybe use `Publish` to shared the observable.

Comment: @fahadash - I've added an alternative solution for you that should behave as you initially expected.

Comment: Yes I know. I meant to make it 1000 times less likely. Yours is even better.... So if I still use the Random generation wrongly as I was earlier, do you think Publish() will take care of it and will not cause the double-call to the generator delegate ?

Comment: @fahadash - Using `Publish` removes the "double-call" as you put it. It doesn't fix the random number generation issue. You're just not using `Random` properly and that's nothing to do with Rx.

Comment: ..and the numbers sequence I think can be further reduced to `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(_=>rnd.NextDouble() * 99 + 2)`. I think this is more expressive i.e. Every second, project a random number from this sequence.